# "Cannot open /var/log/sysstat/sa16 Please check if data collecting is enabled in /etc/default/sysstat"

Tags: linux, unix, io, sar

I want to look at disk I/O info on my machine/in general. Found some help from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io

After recently installing sysstat package and attempting to use sar command (I assume) as that person did, I was instead prompted to check if data collecting was enabled in the above specified file.

After:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/sysstat
```

I changed the only line of uncommented code:

```
ENABLED="false"
```

to:

```
ENABLED="true"
```

However, I am still not able to run sar and get the expected output in my terminal.

Comment: completely missed the iostat -x 1 command that person ran...all good

Comment: ^ If you have an answer, David, would you be able to expand on it in a self-answer below?

Comment: Very good, but remenber restart the sysstat service.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try restarting the service and see the data collects or not

```
$ sudo service sysstat restart
```

Comment: In my case it was disabled, so to make it start on next boot: sudo systemctl enable sysstat

Answer (score 13):

I assume that you have installed the **sysstat** utility properly,

```
apt-get install sysstat
```

**STEP 1**

Open "**/etc/default/sysstat**" using your favorite file editor and change **ENABLED="false"** to **ENABLED="true"**

```
vim /etc/default/sysstat
----
# Should sadc collect system activity informations? Valid values
# are "true" and "false". Please do not put other values, they
# will be overwritten by debconf!
ENABLED="true"
----
```

**STEP 2**

change the collection interval from every 10 minutes to every 2 minutes. So that we get metrics for every two minutes, you can change the interval as per your need.

```
----
vim /etc/cron.d/sysstat
Change
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
To
*/2 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
----
```

**STEP 3**

Next we need to restart the **sysstat** service.

```
service sysstat restart
Or
/etc/init.d/sysstat restart
```

For reference you can click [here](https://www.crybit.com/sysstat-sar-on-ubuntu-debian/)

Answer (score 4):

I install sysstat when I provision new Ubuntu machines so it's scripted.

```
apt-get install sysstat -y
sed -i 's/false/true/g' /etc/default/sysstat
sed -i 's/5-55\/10/*\/2/g' /etc/cron.d/sysstat
service sysstat restart
```

In 15 minutes run this command to see some data ...
`sar -d`

Answer (score 2):

Please follow the steps below to get it to work:
https://www.crybit.com/sysstat-sar-on-ubuntu-debian/

Open `/etc/default/sysstat` using your favorite editor and change `ENABLED="false"` to `ENABLED="true"`

```
$ vi /etc/cron.d/sysstat
```

Change

```
5-55/10 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
```

To:

```
*/2 * * * * root command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1
```

Then:

```
$ service sysstat restart
```

Answer (score 2):

just restart it to reload modified configuration :

```
sudo systemctl restart sysstat.service
```

it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Running `iostat` as:

```
$ iostat -x 1
```

I was able to see the utilization of each device and can now run sar without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

This enabled and started it:

```
sudo sed -i "s|ENABLED="false"|ENABLED="true"|g" /etc/default/sysstat
sudo systemctl enable sysstat && sudo systemctl start sysstat
```

You may need to wait like 15 minutes to start seeing sar values.